# "TypeError: cookies is not iterable"

Tags: node.js, cookies, next.js, jwt, typeerror

I am getting this error while running code. I know the error is in line `response.cookies.set()`.
But not able to solve the problem. Can anyone one provide me solution for these error?

TypeError: cookies is not iterable
at get [headers map sorted] (node:internal/deps/undici/undici:1844:34)
at node:internal/deps/undici/undici:1865:43
at Headers Iterator.next (node:internal/deps/undici/undici:1108:26)
at toNodeOutgoingHttpHeaders (/Users/rajan/Desktop/programming/Projects/writers/node_modules/next/dist/server/web/utils.js:106:31)
at invokeRender (/Users/rajan/Desktop/programming/Projects/writers/node_modules/next/dist/server/lib/router-server.js:275:122)
at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
at async handleRequest (/Users/rajan/Desktop/programming/Projects/writers/node_modules/next/dist/server/lib/router-server.js:447:24)
at async requestHandler (/Users/rajan/Desktop/programming/Projects/writers/node_modules/next/dist/server/lib/router-server.js:464:13)
at async Server. (/Users/rajan/Desktop/programming/Projects/writers/node_modules/next/dist/server/lib/start-server.js:117:13)

```
const tokenData = {
      id: "123",
      username: "username",
      email: "email",
    };

    //Create token
    const token = await jwt.sign(tokenData, process.env.TOKEN_SECRET!, {/* Create token
      expiresIn: "1h",
    });

    
    const response = NextResponse.json({
      message: "Login Success",
      success: true,
    });

    response.cookies.set({
      name: 'token',
      value: token,
      httpOnly: true
    })
    return response;
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are using an older version of Node, try upgrading your Node to the latest LTS version.

I encountered the same issue with Node v18.14.1, and after upgrading it to Node v18.17.1 it works.

You can refer to this [issue](https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/46704) about the known bug.

Hope this helps!